# Visual C++ 2012 std::atomic for non-lock-free types uses spinlock - but what about preemption?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, c++11

Looking into the Visual C++ 2012 implementation of C++11 std atomics, while integer-sized ones are based on interlocked instructions, in xatomic.h we see this:

```
/* ATOMIC OPERATIONS FOR OBJECTS WITH SIZES THAT DON'T MATCH THE SIZE OF ANY INTEGRAL TYPE */
```

And then you see the operations relying on `_Lock_spin_lock(_Flag)`, which is the usual `_interlockedbittestandset` loop.

I thought spinlocks must not be used in user-mode code because a thread could be preempted before unlocking, and any threads waiting for the lock would be busy-waiting. While a `CriticalSection` or SRW lock has a significant overhead, one could spin for a fixed number of times and only then use the heavier weight kernel lock.

Why wouldn't have they done that? On non-ARM platforms, their spinlock doesn't even yield inside the iterations (`_YIELD_PROCESSOR` is only defined as non-blank for ARM).

Comment: My question is exactly the one sentence with a question mark: Why wouldn't have they done that? i.e. why would they use a spinlock given the serious disadvantage mentioned?

Comment: OK, sorry about that, I came to this question because I follow the winapi tag, and I couldn't figure out what it has to do with winapi, `std::atomic` is boost or in the C++ standard I assume. Also the lack of paragraphs made it a bit difficult to read, I edited it so I can remove the downvote, is it OK?